# Order by post meta not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use a custom sortable column for my 'book' post type.

My pre_get_posts function isn't sorting. Each post has an existing meta value for 'downloads_orders', they are all numbers. I have also verified that the code is being run (by dumping out the query)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_book_orderby' );
function my_book_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'downloads_orders' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'downloads_orders');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't sorting?

EDIT: Just realized that none of my sorting is working. Not even the default title column.
EDIT: 'Post types order' Plugin was conflicting, causing no sorting to work. Deactivated this and the above code is now working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_book_orderby' );
function my_book_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'downloads_orders' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'downloads_orders');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    }
}
```